# excel: run time error 424 when filling cells

Tags: vba, excel

I just wrote a simple code to run from the beginning to the end of a column (for example, column 11) on a sheet called `BASE_TOTAL`and everytime it finds an empty cell, it writes "Sem Substituto" on it.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
Sub FillSubs()

Dim i As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("BASE_TOTAL")
Set Lastrow = ws1.Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To Lastrow
    If ws1.Cells(i, 11).Value = "" Then
        ws1.Cells(i, 11).Value = "Sem Substituto"
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

But when I try to run this code, it gives me:

> Run-time error '424' Object required

And highlights this part:

```
Sub FillSubs()
```

Although I don't know what it's wrong with my variables, because I really thought that I declared them right.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: You shouldnt need to SET Lastrow. As below

Lastrow = ws1.Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: You do not `Set` a Long. Remove `Set` from the `Lastrow` line: `Lastrow = ws1.Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: @ScottCraner That's right! Thank you, I don't know why I did this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not "Set" Lastrow

corrected code below

```
Sub FillSubs()

Dim i As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("BASE_TOTAL")
Lastrow = ws1.Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To Lastrow
    If ws1.Cells(i, 11).Value = "" Then
        ws1.Cells(i, 11).Value = "Sem Substituto"
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable Lastrow is a long and as such you do not need to use Set.  Just do this:

```
Lastrow = ws1.Range("A" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```